# ASP.NET Getting value from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code

```
protected void GridView1_DeletingRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Functions con = new Functions();
        SqlConnection con1 = con.get();
        con1.Open();
        TextBox1.Visible = true;
        Button1.Visible = true;
        string z = TextBox1.Text;
        GridView1.EnableViewState = true;
        string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        SqlCommand com3 = new SqlCommand("select id from products where product 
        = '" + name + "' ", con1);
        SqlDataReader read1 = com3.ExecuteReader();
        read1.Read();
        string pro = read1["id"].ToString();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("UPDATE CartItems SET quantity = '" + z 
        + "' where productid = '" + pro + "' ", con1);
    }
```

Error :

```
Line 92:  string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What is the error exactly?  , and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `EventArgs` parameter to the more-specific  `GridViewDeleteEventArgs` type, and use that to find the row being deleted:

```
protected void GridView1_DeletingRow(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    // ...your code
    string name = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
    // ...the rest of your code
```

The most likely reason for your NullReferenceException is because the SelectedRow property is not set when the RowDeleting event is fired.

Note: it's also possible that "`Cells[1].Text`" could throw that exception, if your grid only has one column.  You should review the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) that can help you with debugging NullReferenceExceptions.